# DATE_SUB problem

Tags: php, mysql

my code:

```
$song = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$this->prefix."playlist`  
          WHERE `time` > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 20 MICROSECOND) 
          AND `long` < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 20 MICROSECOND)");
if(mysql_result($song, 0, 0) == 0)
{
  return "כלום";
} else {
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$this->prefix."playlist`  
          WHERE `time` > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 20 MICROSECOND) 
          AND `long` < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 20 MICROSECOND)");
  $song = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

  return $song["song"];
}
```

It should return what song is playing now.

myDB:

```
1   till the worlds ends    2011-06-04 11:20:10 2011-06-04 11:21:10 zRafael
```

the time :

```
11:20
```

it returns:"כלום" Instead the of song name

this my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `playlist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `song` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `long` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `by` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `playlist`
--

INSERT INTO `playlist` (`id`, `song`, `time`, `long`, `by`) VALUES
(1, 'till the worlds ends', '2011-06-04 11:40:10', '10', 'zRafael');
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data and your table schema (SHOW CREATE TABLE xxxx)

Comment: Am I reading this right? You said time should be greater than current time, and in your query and the current time is the same as the song's time, so that means the condition isn't satisfied?

Comment: No I mean we say the song starts at 11:35 and ends at 11:40 The time now is 11:37 shows still "כלום"

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write this to avoid the 2nd query, this should work

**Updated again** - your date fields are VARCHAR, not DATETIME, so my previous query would not have worked.

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT song FROM `".$this->prefix."playlist`  
   WHERE CAST(`time` AS DATETIME) >= NOW() 
   AND CAST(`long` AS DATETIME) < NOW()");
if (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0)
  return "כלום";
else
  return mysql_result($rs, 0);
```

In reality you should fix your table definition.

```
ALTER TABLE `playlist` 
  MODIFY COLUMN `time` DATETIME NOT NULL
  , MODIFY COLUMN `long` DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

Then you will not need those casts and your database lookups will be faster.

Comment: Now it does not bring anything just blank.
code:`$song = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$this->prefix."playlist`  WHERE `time` >= NOW() AND `time`+`long` < NOW()");
   if(mysql_num_rows($song) == 0)
   {
    return "כלום";
   } else {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$this->prefix."playlist`  WHERE `time` >= NOW() AND `time`+`long` < NOW()");
    $song = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    
    return $song["song"];
   }`

Comment: Sorry, just realised that "long" is not a length field, but an end time, I have updated the sql

Comment: Just updated the answer again as your not storing your time & long fileds as DATETIME, but as VARCHAR.